# override identitycolumn hibernate mssql

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have to manage a Datatransfer between 2 DBs (mssql) with hibernate.
When i load an object from one DB with `session.get()` it already has a private key. Then i need to persist it to the other DB with `anotherSession.replicate(Object o)`.
My Problem ist, that the given PK is not persisted but replaced by another one.

PS: Both the srcTable and the destTable have PK generation Identity and it needs to stay that way.

Comment: Look for `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON/OFF`...

Answer (score 0):

If you map an Entity ID with generation "identity", Hibernate will always generate a new ID as soon as you try to persist it. You will have to switch the generation to "assigned" to keep your old ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like it

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id; // still set automatically

}
```

You have to remove the **@GeneratedValue** annotation from **id** field. Else jpa will generate a value for id before insertion.

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id long id; // must be initialized by the application
     :
}
```

### Solution To Your Problem

1. Create a an entity containing all the mapping definition.
2. Create a ID field in your new class without the @Generated value annotation.
3. Clone the old entity to this new one.
4. Persist this new entity.

> Now if you create a subclass extending your entity then the whole
>   process becomes very easy.

### Sample Code For This Solution

**Existing Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EJB_PROJECT")
public class OldEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PROJECT_ID", primaryKey=true)
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;
}
```

**New Entity**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="EJB_PROJECT")
public class NewEntity extends OldEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PROJECT_ID", primaryKey=true)
    Integer id;

    // Constructor to clone old entity's id
    public NewEnity(OldEntity old) {
        this.id = old.id;
    }
}
```

**Persisting code**

```
em.persist(new NewEntity(oldEntity));
```

Comment: is there a way to do that temporarily (i import the @Entity classes from another project that really needs the @GeneratedValue)

Comment: @Mr.H. I have updated my answer with solution. This strategy should work.

Comment: nice idea, it works but it is not the way i am looking for, i need to persist roundabout 200 entities. Your Solution means 200 subclasses to me. Do you have anoter idea that affords a little less work.